# Print/write date to a file only if it's a different day. (Python)

Tags: python, date

I'm doing a maths quiz that asks people questions and at the end it would write their name and score to a file. I want there to be a date before the scores but the way I do it:

```
file1.write(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y" + "\n"))
file1.write("Name: ")
file1.write(Name + "\n")
file1.write("Score: ")
file1.write(str(Score)+ "\n")
file1.write("" + "\n")
file1.close()#
```

Writes the date every time someone finishes the quiz. I want it to write the date only once before a person's results unless it's a new day. For example today is 10/06/2015, it would print this date before the results of the first person that attempts this quiz and then not print the date again until it's a new day like 11/06/2015. Thanks

Comment: Store the date in a variable and then keep checking it against the current date, untill it has changed?

Comment: btw, you can join the writing line in one by doing `file1.write("Name:" + str(Name) + "\n")` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty solution:

```
with open("results.txt", "r+") as f:
    if time.strftime("%d/%m/%y") not in f.read():
        f.write(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y" + "\n"))
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that when I'm using the program again

Answer (score 0):

1 - Get today's date by:

```
myToday = time.strftime('%x')
```

2 - Check whether the date has changed or not:

```
if time.strftime('%x') != myToday:
    myToday = time.strftime('%x') # change today var if it's a new date.
    file1.write(myToday+'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that when I'm back at sixth form